# How can I add dynamic directives to my angular app on the fly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an application where as I need to emulate an os window type behavior. So I need the ability to add multiple windows each with their own context and potentially their own nested directives.

I already have a windowDirective and userProfile directives, I would like to instantiate a new instance of each and add it or remove it from the dom as necessary.

I have thus far attempted to accomplish this with a WindowService using $compile to essentially compile a string with the directive markup in it i.e. `$compile("<window><user-profile></user-profile></window>")(scope)`, which appears to have created a dom tree but spewed a bunch of errors.

Any ideas on how I might approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar.

For starter you need to create a directive which will be your main container (for other windows to be placed inside). Assign a controller to that main container which will retain the list of all other sub-windows you plan to insert/remove. This is needed to clean-up scopes and memory whenever you want to destroy those.

```
var module = angular.module('myModule', []);

module.directive('myContainer', ContainerDirective);
function ContainerDirective() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$compile', function ContainerController($scope, $element, $compile) {
            var winId = 0;
            this.subWindows = {};
            //Create a window
            this.createWindow = function() {
                var subWinElem = angular.element('<my-window>');
                this.subWindows[winId++] = subWinElem;
                $element.append(subWinElem);
                $compile(subWinElem)(scope);
                subWinElem.data('window-id', winId);
                return winId;
            };
            //Destroy a window
            this.destroyWindow = function(winId) {
                if(this.subWindows[winId]) {
                   var subWinElem = this.subWindows[winId],
                       subWinScope = subWinElem.scope();
                   subWinElem.remove();
                   subWinScope.$destoroy();
                   this.subWindows[winId] = null;
                }
            };
            //Clean up on container destroy
            this.dispose = function() {
                angular.forEach(this.subWindows, function(subWinElem) {
                    if(subWinElem) {
                       var subWinScope = subWinElem.scope();
                       subWinElem.remove();
                       subWinScope.$destroy();
                    }
                }); 
            };
       }],
       link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ContainerController) {
          //On click of a button you would create a sub window
          scope.createWindow = function() {
               ContainerController.createWindow();
          };
          //Cleanup anything left in the controller
          $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
             ContainerController.dispose();
          });
       }
    };
}
```

Sub-windows should be directives that would 'require' parent controller. To invoke them dynamically what you can do is append the directive tag first and then $compile the reference to that element (much better then $compile('string')). Because you append element first and then compile you, are able to require parent controller without a problem (since it uses inheritedData).

```
module.directive('myWindow', WindowDirective);
function WindowDirective() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: true,
       require: '?^myContainer',
       link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ContainerController) {
          var winId = elem.data('window-id');
          //You would destroy window like so
          $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              ContainerController.destroyWindow(winId);
          });
       }
   }
}
```

P.S. This is a much simplified example (and may contain typos :P) but you get the gist of it.

Comment: This is a fantastic approach! I haven't applied it yet, but it looks like exactly what I want to do. I'm new to Angular js so still getting footing. Thank you much. :)

Comment: Trying to implement this and I'm having trouble understanding where I initially instantiate the window? I'd like to not use ng-repeat and have a bunch of window tags in the dom, but from a controller function instantiate a new window directive and insert it into the dom at that point. The issue is I won't have a angular $element to work from at that point?

Comment: If you are operating within a scope of the container directive you just call a createWindow method and it will spawn a new window for you. If you want to control that process yourself, you may want to create a new 'window' node yourself using document.createElement and go through the process similar to createWindow method of container controller. You don't need ng-repeat :).